# What is the easiest way to implement a graph of strings(cities)?

Tags: c++, graph

I have already implemented an adjacency matrix graph which uses just integers types.(consider C++ for everything that I mention here)

I'm implementing another graph that will receive cities in the vertexes and distances in the edges using my old implementation. I was wondering if this is a good idea or I should use a different implementation for this problem like linked lists. The idea here is to read all the cities and their distances to each other from a txt file, add it in the graph and then display a menu to the user so he/she can consult the distance from city A to B and get a list of all the cities he needs to travel before they reach the target.

I'm planning to read the city, give it a number code, and add it in the graph, instead of adding the string "city" (would need to convert the graph from integer to string)

What do you think,any idea/advice?

Comment: You can use Boost Graph Library.

Comment: A Double Linked List could be an idea to implement your graph.

Comment: If you want to use your old integer types graph, just use `std::map<int, string>` to store the string representation of your city. Use your graph as usual, then map the integer id to data string when presenting your graph to user.

Comment: I have never used map lib so far. I was reading about it but I couldn't figure out how to use it, can you be more specific ?   For example: when I want to insert in the graph , I'll use   map<int,string> x = {1, city}    graph->insert(x)

Answer (score 1):

You can use either map for that. Like this

> `map<pair<string,string>,int> city ;`

(See implementation 2) 
Or you can use vector to keep track of city names with their index(implementation 1)

**Implementation 1**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<map>
using namespace std;

class Graph
{
    int V; // start vertice 
    map<pair<string,string>,int> city ;
    vector<string> city1;
    vector<string> city2;
    public:
    Graph(int start_V)
    {
        V = start_V;
    }
    void addEdge(string start,string end,int wt);
    void display();
};
void Graph::addEdge(string start,string end,int wt)
{   
   city[make_pair(start,end)] = wt;
}
void Graph::display()
{   
    int flag=0;
    for(auto it:city)
    {
        city1.push_back(it.first.first);
        city2.push_back(it.first.second);
    }

    sort(city1.begin(), city1.end()); 
    auto last = unique(city1.begin(), city1.end());
    city1.erase(last, city1.end());

    sort(city2.begin(), city2.end()); 
    auto last2 = unique(city2.begin(), city2.end());
    city2.erase(last2, city2.end());

    for(auto col:city2)
    {
        cout<<"\t"<<col;
    }
    cout<<"\n";

    for(auto row:city1)
    {
    int flag =0;   //for printing row for once 
    for(auto col:city2)
    {
        if (!flag)
            cout<<row;
        cout<<"\t"<<city[make_pair(row,col)];
        flag = 1;
    }

    cout<<"\n";
    }

}
int main()
{
    Graph g(2);

    g.addEdge("A","B",1);
    g.addEdge("C","A",5);
    g.addEdge("D","E",7);
    g.addEdge("E","A",5);
    g.addEdge("D","B",7);
    g.addEdge("D","L",7);
    g.addEdge("W","L",7);
    g.display();
    return 0;
}
```

**Implementation 2**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<map> 
using namespace std;

class Graph {
    int V; // start vertice 
    map<pair<string,string>,int> city ;
    vector<string> city1;
    vector<string> city2;
    public:
    Graph(int start_V)
    {
        V = start_V;
    }
    void addEdge(string start,string end,int wt);
    void display(); }; void Graph::addEdge(string start,string end,int wt) {       city[make_pair(start,end)] = wt; } void Graph::display() {

    int flag=0;
    for(auto it:city)
    {
        city1.push_back(it.first.first);
        city2.push_back(it.first.second);
    }

    sort(city1.begin(), city1.end()); 
    auto last = unique(city1.begin(), city1.end());
    city1.erase(last, city1.end());

    sort(city2.begin(), city2.end()); 
    auto last2 = unique(city2.begin(), city2.end());
    city2.erase(last2, city2.end());

    for(auto col:city2)
    {
        cout<<"\t"<<col;
    }
    cout<<"\n";

    for(auto row:city1)
    {
    int flag =0;   //for printing row for once 
    for(auto col:city2)
    {
        if (!flag)
            cout<<row;
        cout<<"\t"<<city[make_pair(row,col)];
        flag = 1;
    }

    cout<<"\n";
    }
     } int main() {
    Graph g(2);

    g.addEdge("A","B",1);
    g.addEdge("C","A",5);
    g.addEdge("D","E",7);
    g.addEdge("E","A",5);
    g.addEdge("D","B",7);
    g.addEdge("D","L",7);
    g.addEdge("W","L",7);
    g.display();
    return 0; }
```